# About the TabWidget in android

Tags: android, tabwidget

I set up setcontent（intent）in TabWidget. But I want to make a check before switch. If the condition was established it will switch. If not it won’t switch. How to realize this?

After switch it will return last activity default and save the relevant information. How to let it reload every time?

Comment: here what is you condition to check for switch?? Do you want to restrict the user to go to the activity or you wil start another activity OR just show a message to user. Please be specific

Comment: @Narendra Pal I want to realize like : if the Judgment conditions false, give a toast hint and do not skip. if the condition true, it will skip. thanks very much!

Comment: Okay, so when you are setting the view on the frame,at that time you can check

Comment: basically I have created a custom vertical tabs.So in my design, i have tab widget and frame layout. So i can control this requirement simply. if possible for you,post some code.so it will be better to help you